# cannot run a command from a PyQt window

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pyqt5, command

I'm trying to write a small GUI (with PyQt) with a few buttons that run commands I use often. I want these commands to be executed in the terminal from with I launch the GUI.

On Linux, from another terminal, this can be achieved with `the_command > /dev/pts/x`.

Here the code I wrote:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import fcntl
from functools import partial
import subprocess
import sys
import termios

# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
# run script from a Linux terminal to get a tty!


# run a command in the terminal
def run_term_cmd(cmd, tty):
    with open(tty, 'w') as fd:
        for c in cmd:
            fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, c)
        fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, "\n")


# return the current tty (eg. /dev/pts/4)
def get_tty():
    cp = subprocess.run("tty", capture_output=True, check=True)
    return cp.stdout.decode().rstrip()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, cmds, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        btn = QPushButton("run ls")
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

        btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.btn_clicked, "ls -al /"))

    def btn_clicked(self, cmd):
        run_term_cmd(cmd, get_tty())


# switch this to run with/without Qt
use_gui = True

if not use_gui:
    run_term_cmd("ls -al", get_tty())
else:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(sys.argv)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Without GUI (`use_gui = False`), this works. With GUI on, the command output is displayed after the window is closed.

Why ?

Comment: You're simulating terminal input, and any typed command will only execute after the *current* program has exited (unless the program handles terminal input). That would be the same as typing the same command *by hand* in the terminal while the program is running: the command will not be executed until the program has quit. Are you sure you *really* want to run the command in the current tty? Maybe you just want to show the *output*? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: > What are you actually trying to achieve?

Simulate the typing of a key sequence (including Return/Enter key) in a terminal to avoid typing again and again the same things (not only for shell commands but also for example gdb commands or whatever terminal application).
I'm trying to write a GUI with a few buttons, each sending a key sequence to the terminal window which the GUI was launched from.

> Are you sure you really want to run the command in the current tty?

I want the key sequence to be send to the current tty, not run the command (probably my code is misleading (ioctl))